# How to unregister SensorEventListener from SensorManaget?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the application which uses SensorManager through SensorEventListener. But there is a one problem: when application starts it should remove my listener from SensorManager and create a new Listener, but SensorManager has only 2 methods - registerListener and unregisterListener, but when I execute the application I can't get a reference for last listener and unregister it. Please, tell me any way in order to I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: where you are unregistering your listener..

Comment: Sorry, I have just got the decision of my problem. But now I have 1 question to be fixed - how can I get all running services in order to stop one?

Answer (score 0):

Don't kill process its not a good idea. Here is the code to detect services.

```
    ActivityManager activity_manager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> current_services = activity_manager.getRunningServices(50);

    for (int i=0; i<current_services.size(); i++) {
      ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo temp_service = current_services.get(i);
      if (temp_service.getClass().equals("your complete class name with package")) {
          //DO YOUR WORK HERE.
           android.os.Process.killProcess(temp_service.pid); //TO KILL PROCESS BUT I RECOMMEND DON'T KILL IT.
      }
    }
```